# How to configure different prefixes for different bundles in api-platform

Tags: rest, symfony, api-platform.com

Console command `debug:router` show absolutely ALL resources, from all installed Bundles (entity marked with @ApiResource())

How to configure different prefixes for different bundles?
Or selectively disable resources.

App ignored any path in `resource`: `config/routes/api_platform.yaml`

```yaml
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api
```

With default config `config/packages/api_platform.yaml`

```yaml
api_platform:
  mapping:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve? You can disable operations on an ApiResource via config, see: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations is that what you need?

Comment: Set prefix for all resources from a specific bundle. Like `resource: @BundleName\Entity` prefix: /other-prefix - To get routes /other-prefix/resourse ... and set access_control: - { path: ^/other-prefix, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } for all Bundle resources in APP level

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/5882990beaf75675170efb54384bf44c3534dd1b/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/ApiLoader.php

For `type: api_platform` `resource: .` not used

Automatic resource loading can only be disabled completely

```yaml
  doctrine:
    enabled: false
```