# How to configure routing with yaml?

Tags: api-platform.com

What can be used instead of a dot?

```yaml
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api
```

### v2.5.5 (latest)

Nothing works for me. More precisely. Nothing changes. The same result.

```yaml
resource: '@BundleName/Entity' # eg
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? I don't understand why you want to change this value. (You certainly have a good reason, but I don't know it, so it's difficult to help you.)

Comment: This is not in the documentation. Does anyone know how to use this setting?

Comment: I want to specify a different prefix for different resources through this setting. This is for a third-party bundle.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475504/how-to-configure-different-prefixes-for-different-bundles-in-api-platform